# RockBand-like voice app for PC/OSX / Real time pitch display software

Tags: detection, pitch

I played Rock Band 2 for the first time a little while ago (at Notacon).

One thing I enjoyed about it was getting real-time feedback about my
singing. I think it'd be neat to have something like that to run
alongside my usual music, so that I can sing to random stuff in my
music collection and know when I'm hitting the notes.

Is there something like this for PC - ideally for OSX, and ideally
that can just operate on arbitrary songs?

I don't really care if it's game-like (though that's neat too); I just
want it for the singing feedback. And I have no need for pitch *correction* - ideally what I'd see is just the pitches of the notes in the music and (on the same scale, differently displayed) of the live microphone.

I tried to STFW but got no salient hits. :-/

Thanks!

Comment: Belongs on superuser.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Performous](http://performous.org/) is a multi-OS open source alternative to rock band

Comment: Pity that a) it's not capable of automatically extracting the metadata for any mp3 (... though I realize that's Hard™) and b) it's got very little manually transcribed yet. But hey, what can you expect from OSS? :-P

Answer (score 1):

Check out Passaggio.  It is a real time voice analyzer for singers that runs in Windows or on the IPhone. You can clearly see voice pitch, volume and vocal quality against a musical staff. It is designed to be a help to singers.

See http://www.wivllc.com